# Deserializar um Objeto de Outro

Tags: java, json, jackson

Estou tentando deserializar três classes DTOS para exportar para um arquivo JSON, consegui fazer boa parte do processo mas quando tento exportar uma classe dentro de outra não consigo.

segue os seguinte cenarios:

```
public class TakeOffPoliciesDto {

private List<ExportTakeOffDto> exportTakeOffDto;

public List<ExportTakeOffDto> getExportTakeOffDto() {
    return exportTakeOffDto;
}

public void setExportTakeOffDto(List<ExportTakeOffDto> exportTakeOffDto) {
    this.exportTakeOffDto = exportTakeOffDto;
}

public class ExportTakeOffDto {


private List<FamilyTypeDto> familyTypeDtos;
private List<AirportPolicieDto> airportPolicieDtos;

public List<FamilyTypeDto> getFamilyTypeDtos() {
    return familyTypeDtos;
}

public void setFamilyTypeDtos(List<FamilyTypeDto> familyTypeDtos) {
    this.familyTypeDtos = familyTypeDtos;
}

public List<AirportPolicieDto> getAirportPolicieDtos() {
    return airportPolicieDtos;
}

public void setAirportPolicieDtos(List<AirportPolicieDto> airportPolicieDtos) {
    this.airportPolicieDtos = airportPolicieDtos;
}



private void exportToJSonFile() {

    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    TakeOffPoliciesDto takeOffPoliciesDto = new TakeOffPoliciesDto();

    takeOffPoliciesDto.setExportTakeOffDto(Arrays.asList("1111", "9998887654", "1234567890"));

    ExportTakeOffDto exportDto = new ExportTakeOffDto();

    exportDto.setFamilyTypeDtos( Arrays.asList("8095185442", "9998887654", "1234567890"));
    exportDto.setAirportPolicieDtos( Arrays.asList("8095185442", "9998887654", "1234567890"));

    try {
    objectMapper.writeValue(new File(file.getAbsolutePath(), "teste.json"), takeOffPoliciesDto);


    } catch (JsonGenerationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual o problema?

Comment: Quando tento deserializar um objeto dentro de outro ele vem nulo ,

Comment: E onde está o Json da deserialização?

Comment: Eu estou tentando pegar esse valores direto do Banco, tenho uma classe mode, e criei um DTO especifico para elas

Comment: E qual é o dado do banco?

Answer (score 0):

Consegui usando o ModelMapper uma biblioteca que copia os dados dos meus models e transfere para os DTOS, ficou assim :

```
     private void exportToJSonFile() {

      ObjectMapper objectMapper = new 
     ObjectMapper().enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);

    ExportAllDTo exportAllDTo = new ExportAllDTo();

    List<FamilyPoliciesEntity> familyPoliciesEntities = 
    familyPoliciesService.findAll();
    List<FamilyPolicieDto> familyPoliciesDtoList = new ArrayList<>();

    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
  for (FamilyPoliciesEntity familyPoliciesEntity : familyPoliciesEntities) {

        try {

            FamilyPolicieDto familyPoliciesDto = mapper.map(familyPoliciesEntity, 
            FamilyPolicieDto.class);

            TakeoffConfigurationEntity takeoffConfigurationEntity = 
           takeoffConfigurationService
                    .recoverByPolicy(familyPoliciesEntity);

    try {

        exportAllDTo.setTakeoff(familyPoliciesDtoList);
        objectMapper.writeValue(new File(file.getAbsolutePath(), "teste.json"), 
        exportAllDTo);
        String jsonString = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(exportAllDTo);
```